# Arrays with for loops give segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a program which store three different marks as arrays. When I run the program I get the following error:

```
Enter marks: 95
Enter marks: 64
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the program I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        int num[3];
        int i;
        float total;

        for (i=0;i<4;i++) {

                printf("Enter marks: ");
                scanf("%d", num[i]);
        }

        total = num[0] + num[1] + num[2] / 300 * 100;

        printf("Average: %.2f", total);
}
```

Comment: Your loop should be `< 3`.

Comment: @user3121023 ops that is a silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

The first (as others have noted) is that you need to `scanf` into a location thus:

```
scanf("%d", &num[1]);
```

Not doing this is causing a segmentation fault.

You also need to get your array size and loop limit to match.

You have defined your array as:

```
int num[3];
```

which has indexes 0, 1, 2.

However your loop

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
```

iterates from 0..3.

Once you fix your first issue, you will reference `num[3]` which is invalid and will cause another error.